# How to save retrofit array to sqlite database?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, retrofit

here is my jsonString:

```
{  
   "status":1,
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":"39",
         "friendsInfo":{  
            "email":"test@gmail.com",
            "phone":null,
            "language":"en"
         }
      },
      {  
         "id":"39",
         "friendsInfo":{  
            "email":"test@gmail.com",
            "phone":null,
            "language":"en"
         }
      }
   ],
   "message":""
}
```

here is my receivingClass:

```
public class mAnswer{

    @SerializedName("status")
    public int mEnterStatus;

    @SerializedName("data")
    public List<Data> dataList;

    public class Data {
        @SerializedName("id")
        public int mUserId;
        @SerializedName("friendsInfo")
        public GetUserDetails getUserDetails;

        public class GetUserDetails{
            @SerializedName("email")
            public int email;
            @SerializedName("phone")
            public String phone;
            @SerializedName("language")
            public String language;    
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my code for successful receiving answer where I am trying to save this data to SQLite db:

```
private void saveList(){
        Vector<ContentValues> cVVector = new Vector<ContentValues>();

        int arraySize = mAnswer.dataList.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){

            // **HERE IS PROBLEM**

            cVVector.add(friendsValue);

        }

        if (arraySize > 0 ){
            ContentValues[] cvArray = new ContentValues[arraySize];
            cVVector.toArray(cvArray);

            mContext.getContentResolver().
                    bulkInsert(J4D_DB_Contract.UserFriendsEntry.CONTENT_URI, cvArray);
        }
    }
```

So here is my problem:
how to correct call @SerializedName elements when i am trying to save List data to db?

any ideas? 
Will be glad any help! Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your database create table query. Then i know about your db structure

Answer (score 0):

```
mAnswer.dataList.get(0);
```

gives back the

```
 "id":"39",
     "friendsInfo":{  
        "email":"test@gmail.com",
        "phone":null,
        "language":"en"
     }
```

this is what you should say in the loop:

```
  mAnswer.dataList.get(0).getFriendsObject().getEmail();
  mAnswer.dataList.get(0).getFriendsObject().getPhone();
```

I would use this site to generate my POJO, beucase it`s more cleaner I think. 
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
This site gives back well defined POJO architecture, what is ready for use.
Just set that you are working with JSON instead of JSON Scheme and using GSON (if you are using retrofit).

After you can copy your java files to your workplace.

You don't need the `@SerializedName("jsonName")` if the variable has the same name `private String jsonName;`